# How to ask for apologies when you have already sent an email by not pressing the reply to all feature?

Tags: politeness, email

Three days ago I replied to an email that I was in BCC list by pressing only reply to feature.Now I realized that I haven't pressed the reply to all feature,that I was supposed to do so.

Now I want to send another or the same email again by choosing reply to all.

How can I explain my mistake and convey my apologies?

This is what I wrote :

Dear..
I owe you an apology.
On Friday 21th of February, when I replied to your email I made a mistake.
Today when I opened my Gmail to send you the Xxx file that I had told you already about, I realized, I not only totally forgot that I were in bcc list but I also attached the Zzz file that was irrelevant to that email.
Please accept my sincerest apologies for the mistake or omission that may cause you any inconvienece.
I have already replied to that email in proper way.
I promise it won't happen again.
Thank you very much for your understanding.

Comment: Thank you so much for editing my post but it is bcc feature not BBC.

Comment: .@Sarina I've submitted an edit to correct this

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You may have any idea on how can I explain my mistake and convey my apologies?

Comment: As a matter of etiquette, you should never reply to a message you received by BCC. To do so is to betray the trust of the original sender, who did not wish that the ordinary recipients know that you received a copy.